# Is it too late to leverage Apple Tesla upcoming stock split?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets

Today is Sunday Aug 30. Apple and Tesla are planning stock splits tomorrow ie Monday Aug 31: Tesla is set to enact a 5-for-1 split, while Apple is set to enact a 4-for-1 split. Both are expected to surge by 33% over the first year post split.

Is it too late to buy these at market open tomorrow? I am planning to place a market order on the TDAmeritrade App timed to execute as soon as possible on (Aug 31) market open. But I’m worried that since the split is also scheduled for tomorrow will my purchase be  considered to be after the split? Does that make a difference to my upside if the stock values increase by say the predicted 33%?

Comment: "... stock values increase by say the predicted 33%" Where does this 33% number come from? Is that your own prediction?

Comment: I can see that very strange ideas on "stockl splits!" are promulgated to the average civilian not involved with the markets, perhaps on news TV? Or on "internet blogs"?  Strange stuff.

Comment: If everybody knows that a stock is going to go up tomorrow they'll all buy it today and it will go up today instead.

Comment: Oh yee of little faith!  Right now TSLA is down 33% post split since August 31st.  What amazing predictive power your source has!!!  One small detail.  It got the direction wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The split already happened. (Anecotally, I already see the additional shares of AAPL in my brokerage account on the morning of August 30.)

For each share of AAPL that you owned at the close of business on August 24, Apple delivered to you 3 additional shares *after* the close of business on August 28. (If you bought stock between August 24 and August 31, you would receive the new shares from whoever you bought the stock from, rather than directly from Apple.)

The new shares should appear in your account sometime between the close of business on August 28 and prior to the market reopening on the morning of August 31. When the market does reopen, the share price will be 1/4th what it was on August 28, to reflect the new total number of shares. Since AAPL closed at $499.23 on August 28, it will resume trading at $124.808 (which way it rounds, if at all, I do not know). Any order you place now will be at the new price. (Additionally, any *open* orders at the close of business on August 28 will be adjusted for the new price as well.)

If the price does increase by 33% over the next year, it doesn't matter if you bought one share at $499.23 late Friday or four shares at $124.808 early Monday; it's your total *investment* that will increase. The *value* of a stock isn't affected by the split, only its per-share *price*.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your source about future price movement in AAPL and TSLA is correct that **both are expected to surge by 33% over the first year post split**, do you  realize that one year isn't tomorrow?

If you are convinced that it is a good time to buy AAPL and/or TSLA right now, buy it first thing in the morning when pre-market trading begins, assuming that your broker offers this service and that you have account authorization to trade in the pre/post market.

When a stock split occurs, share price is adjusted by the inverse of the split ratio. If share price was $400 before a 4 for 1 split, on the day of the split, the position will become four times as many shares at $100 which means that position value is unchanged. What happens to price when trading resumes will depend on if there are more net buying orders than selling orders or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The split on AAPL and TSLA is already done. So you would buy it already after the split. I wouldn't recommend you doing that. Both stocks surged already more than 40 % on the split rumors and news. There will be lots of selling pressure in the morning, the question is will the demand be higher than the supply? It's hard to say because many new market participants will come into the market, but anybody knows that or anticipated that already.

It's highly unpredictable if you ask me. If you really want to buy I would wait till lunchtime.